# how can one user create userlevel variable for other users

Tags: powershell

A windows server has 20 users as usr01 - usr20. For particular application, each users should have user level environment variable such as LDTP_PORT but different values as 4001 for usr 1 and 4020 for usr20.

As manual process , I could log on as each user and update but not possible for 30 servers. I tried through codes but it needs explicit log in as specific user.

I look for powershell or some other way as one user (who is admin user) could set the user level variable for all other users. I do not want to work with -SID- at registry HKU as I am not sure how to map the user with SID)

Comment: What problem is this solving? If an application needs to know which user is logged on, it can read `$Env:USERNAME` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that there is one simple way, but not really elegant.

Since port number is not sensitive data (because in your case, you can easily predict other user's ports), I would just make 20 global variables, so everyone will have his own. For example:
User with username `$env:userName`, will have his port in `$env:userNameLPTPort`.

So code will be as simple as this:

```
$firstLPTPort = 4000
ForEach ($userName in $usersList) {
    $newEnvVariableName = "env:" + $userName + "LPTPort"

    #machine means that the scope is for whole machine and it wont disappear after closing the session
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($newEnvVariableName, $firstLPTPort, "Machine")
    $firstLPTPort++
}
```

To confirm, that it works, use this:

```
echo ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($envName,"Machine"))
```

Remember that SetEnvironemtVariable function, will not throw exception, if there is already one variable with this name, but just simply overwrite the old one.

Edit:

You can also specify scope for specific user, just change this:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($newEnvVariableName, $firstLPTPort, "Machine")
```

into this:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($newEnvVariableName, $firstLPTPort, $userName)
```

But make sure, that `$usersList` contains correct user names.